# Cannot get MaxHeapify to work properly

Tags: java, heap

Well, I have spent over 8 hours working on this. I have copied the example from the book verbatim, as well as trying to implement the heap based on other resources online. I still cannot get the heap to work right. Here is what I have coded so far:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Heap{

static int[] arr;
static int heapSize;
static int max = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keys = new Scanner(in);

    out.print("Enter size of heap desired: ");                      //Receive input from user regarding
    int arrSize = keys.nextInt();                                   //desired heap size

    ArrayBuild(arrSize);            //Call builder to construct array based on user desired size

    heapSize = arr.length;

    int start = arr.length/2-1;

    MaxHeapify(start);

    keys.close();

}

public static void ArrayBuild(int size){           //Constructs new array based on given size
    arr = new int[size];

    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
        arr[i] = new Random().nextInt(10)+1;
}

public static void MaxHeapify(int i){

        int left = 2*i;
        int right = 2*i+1;

        if(left <= heapSize && arr[left] > arr[i]){
            max = left;
        }else{
            max = i;
        }

        if(right <= heapSize && arr[right] > arr[max]){
            max = right;
        }

        if(max != i){
            swap(i, max);
            MaxHeapify(max);
        }
}

public static void BuildMaxHeap(){
    for(int i=(arr.length/2); i>0; i--)
        MaxHeapify(i);
}

public static void swap(int i, int max){
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[max];
    arr[max] = temp;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

2 problems:

```
int left = 2 * i;
int right = 2 * i + 1;
```

Should be:

```
int left = 2 * i + 1;
int right = 2 * i + 2;
```

Java arrays are 0 based so for the root (which is the first element) with your formula is for cases when you use a 1 based array. In Java the left child would be also 0 as 2*0=0 from what I remember etc.

Second when you are building the heap in `main()` you need to run `MaxHeapify()` for half of the elements like you're doing in `BuildMaxHeap()`, not only for the middle one, like this:

```
for(int start = arr.length / 2 - 1; start >= 0; start--) {
    MaxHeapify(start);
}
```

Also in `BuildMaxHeap()` you should change the stop condition to `>=` and start at `arr.length / 2 - 1`.

Hope this helps.